# How can I do the instruction level debugging with CDT

Tags: c, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I am using CDT for developing C programs.

When the debugger stops on a break point and I do "Step Over" or "Step Into" the debugger behaviour is based on the source line level but not on the instruction level.

Can I do debugging on the instruction level in CDT?

Comment: There's a way to get it to show you the assembly, then you can step one instruction at a time, I don't remember how to do that though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the **Debug** window (Debug perspective) there is an **Instruction Stepping Mode** button: It looks like a small i with an arrow `i=>`).
You can also set breakpoints on specific instructions in the Disassembly window.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CDT is just a wrapper over a standalone debugger.  So I'd suggest skipping CDT and checking the documentation of the debugger you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction Stepping Mode can also be activated from the menu. While debugging:

- Run
- Instruction Stepping Mode

This asks how to enable it by default: [How to enable instruction stepping in eclipse-cdt (Eclipse for C++) by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370781/how-to-enable-instruction-stepping-in-eclipse-cdt-eclipse-for-c-by-default)

Tested on 4.6.3.