# How to step in to code implementing new(), on Eclipse, on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, runtime, malloc

I have this tiny C++ program in Eclipse IDE, on Ubuntu 13.10 (GCC and g++ 4.8.1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* a = new int(4);     //I want to see what happens here at a low-level
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I would like to be able to step-in to the new() function and then keep stepping in as far as I can before I start hitting assembly code. I am trying to understand what happens when memory is allocated.

However, right now when I debug the project and step-in on the line containing `new()` the debugger just steps over?

EDIT: I think part of the answer is that I actually have to install the libraries I wish to step in to? and then possibly tell Eclipse about these libraries? **Is this correct anyone? How would I do this?**

Comment: Use the Instruction Stepping Mode (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112420/how-can-i-do-the-instruction-level-debugging-with-cdt)

Comment: @Samuel_xL not a duplicate- I dont want to see the assembly instructions. I want to see what malloc() does exactly (but at the C level)

Comment: You can't. There are no symbols and source; all you can do is watch it at assembly level.

Comment: So there is no way to be able to "step in" to the Linux implementation of malloc() from within Eclipse?!

Comment: @user997112 You won't be able to, the "step in" is precisely the assembly code. But you're right about the duplicate : I read "I want to see assembly code" instead of "before I start hitting assembly code"

Comment: Ok- is it fair to say I will have a better chance of achieving this on Visual Studio with the Microsoft run-time? On that I can get down to just outside heap_alloc. I thought I would have a better chance being able to see more on Linux.

Comment: @bmargulies you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027693/step-into-system-crtl-functions-with-eclipse-in-linux?rq=1

"Going back to the usermode, which you CAN debug via Eclipse, essentially all you need to do is install the source code for the runtime library you are interested in, and go... Same principle as on Windows with visual studio - except that nearly all software you ever run on a Linux system is available as source code."

Comment: Assuming the above comment/quote from me means it is possible could anyone help me do this?

Comment: The copy of malloc you are running is sitting in libc.so, it is not compiled with symbols, you can't step through it. Of course, you could compile another version of malloc and link that and step into it.

Comment: The debugger providing `step` ability is *not* Eclipse. It is `gdb` (for which Eclipse provides a tiny graphic wrapper). Eclipse is just a glorified editor (a.k.a.  *IDE*).

Answer (score 1):

When you code says 'new', the compiler maps that to a call to 'operator new'. That can be one of several things, depending on whether you are allocating an array, or a class with a class-specific operator new, or both. For `new int(4)`, you are calling:

`:operator new(size_t)`

That function is part of the C++ run time library. It eventually gets around to calling `malloc` if it feels like it. By default, that library has no installed debugging symbols. If you want to debug into it, you have to set up shop as if you were a developer of the library: download the source of it, compile it with symbols, and persuade Eclipse to use the version you just built. This is, well, an advanced technique. You'd better really understand what is *really* happening with `make` and `gdb` before you try to use Eclipse in this neighborhood.

Comment: what exactly are "symbols"?

Comment: I presume the easiest way would be to download the runtime source files and just use a program which allows me to ctrl + f for each function definition?

Comment: Nope. You still won't be able to step. You can read the code, but without debugging symbols, the debugger can't correlate the machine code to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Some points to answer your question.

<sup>(I gave some of them in a comment that I have deleted since).</sup>

- Eclipse is not a debugger (or a compiler), just a glorified editor (a.k.a. [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)). You don't really need it (and I find more convenient to use the `emacs` editor for development; it is really a matter of opinion and taste). It provides a graphical interface to `gdb` the [GNU debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) (and you could use `gdb` in a terminal, start it as `gdb -tui`) and to your compiler `g++` (perhaps by running `make`). You really are going `step` by step into code with `gdb`. Eclipse just gives you nice looking buttons for that (but runs a `gdb` process).
- You need debugging symbols and information to `step` into some function, so that code should be compiled by GCC with `-g` flag to the compiler.
- You could with pain compile the GNU libc library [Glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), and the `libstdc++` (provided by your version of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler)  with debugging symbols ...
- You probably want to install the debugging Debian or Ubuntu packages `libstdc++6-4.8-dbg` and `libc6-dbg` which provide the debugging symbols and information of `libstdc++` (for `g++-4.8`) and of `libc6`
- You'll still need to get the source code of the corresponding `libstdc++6-4.8` and `libc6` packages to really `step` inside their source code with ease
- You probably want to use the `set debug-file-directory` command (probably to `/usr/lib/debug`) of `gdb`; I have no idea if Eclipse is interfacing it. Maybe using `gdb` directly in a terminal is easier.
- You should use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt memory leaks. Recent [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) also gives you its *address sanitizer* (with `-fsanitize=address`)
- At last, `::operator new` is a [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) primitive in C++; it usually calls `malloc` (implemented in `libc6`) which is ultimately using the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) system call (or [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall)) atomicly provided by the [linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel).