# How to enable instruction stepping in eclipse-cdt (Eclipse for C++) by default?

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, eclipse-cdt

I repeatedly debug a program in Eclipse CDT in instruction stepping mode, i.e. a "step over" causes the next assembler/machine code instruction to be executed rather than the next line of C/C++ code.

Because I do it over and over again, it nags me to have to press the "instruction stepping" button again for every execution. Is there a way to enable it by default? I tried to find it in the debug configuration settings of the program that I debug, but I didn't find it there.

Comment: Just out of personal curiosity: What is your usecase? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I expected this question :) I'm writing my own JIT compiler - mostly for fun - for optimizing code at runtime. So what I'm debugging is not assembler which is directly based on C/C++ code, but transformed code for which no direct equivalent C/C++ source exists.

Answer (score 1):

By default local launch is using new debugging framework called DSF which
does not remember this settings (at least in mars), however old one did remember it.
You can switch to old one using the following steps:

Open launch configuration

Click on link at the bottom to switch Launcher (on any page)

Select "Legacy Create Process Launcher"

If you use this one now if you press instruction stepping mode it will remember it for the next session